# Can I use a protocol array in ForEach?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've got a protocol with two classes that implement it:

```swift
protocol GalleryItem {
    func toView() -> AnyView
}

extension Class1:GalleryItem {
    func toView() -> AnyView {
      ...
    }
}

extension Class2:GalleryItem {
    func toView() -> AnyView {
      ...
    }
}
```

An array:

```swift
var array:[GalleryItem] = [Class1(), Class2()]
```

Now if I try to use that array in a ForEach:

```swift
ForEach(array, id: \.self) { item in
  item.toView()
}
```

I get this error:

```
Value of protocol type 'GalleryItem' cannot conform to 'Hashable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
```

Does that mean I can't have a protocol array like this passed to ForEach? How else would I accomplish this?

Comment: This is not what "generic" means.

Comment: @Jessy what does generic mean?

Comment: It's the page after the protocols page. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html You are talking about protocols. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html

Comment: I did start my question with "I've got a protocol...". What would you call a list like this? I used "generic" to mean "could hold many types of items". Would you say "protocol list"?

Comment: "Protocol Array". Which is not a "list", either, in this ecosystem. List is a SwiftUI-specific term now, and didn't exist before as official terminology.

Comment: Good to know. I don't think it's called "protocol array" in too many other languages, and I am new to swift, so I'm glad to have learned something. I don't think I would have got there with your initial comment though, please give more detail the first time next time. Just saying, essentially, "you are wrong", is not helpful.

Comment: Fair enough. However, you should look up the words you put into a question before typing them. Two of them are incorrect, and you should edit this! It's confusing and probably won't help people in the future, because search won't turn this up.

Comment: That's fair, edited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, let's make it work.

### The issue

In your case, the compiler expects parameter `\.self` to be `Hashable` and this parameter is an object of your protocol `GalleryItem`.

### The solution

To solve this, we can add a requirement to the protocol that can provide an `\.id`. For example:

```swift
protocol GalleryItem {
    func toView() -> AnyView
    var id: Int { get }       // could be any `Hashable` type
}
```

And then, instead of using `\.self` in the ForEach as identifier, we can use `\.id` as an identifier:

```swift
ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
    item.toView()
}
```

The naming and the type here are pretty much up to you. `\.id` and `Int` are used as an example.